# Troubleshoot Docker-On-Windows attempt to run hello-world

Tags: windows, docker, boot2docker

I have installed docker on windows and successfully brought up the bash shell window.   However, when I test my installation with `docker run hello-world` I get the following:

> Post http://127.0.0.1:2375/v1.20/containers/create: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:2375: ConnectEx tcp: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it..
>   * Are you trying to connect to a TLS-enabled daemon without TLS?
>   * Is your docker daemon up and running?

I thought at first it was because I needed to be logged in to docker hub.  When I tried `docker login` and gave it my docker-hub account name, I got

> The handle is invalid.

BTW, it did *not* ask me for my password.
I am puzzled.  Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little more troubleshooting helped resolve the problem.  Steps taken:

- I ran the new program Kitematic.  It complained that it could not run the VM and offered a remove-and-setup-again option.
- I chose the remove-and-setup-again option.
- I then ran Kitematic again and it prompted for my dockerhub credentials
- Once I successfully entered those and Kitematic seemed healthy I tried the `Quickstart terminal` again.
- Running that provoked some checks from my anti-virus software which wanted to block internet activity from the VM.  Once I overrode that, all went well.

In conclusion, it seems that retrying an install does change things (I do not know why) and secondly,  anti-virus software can be a bother.

Comment: I had the same issue as yourself and resolved it by erasing the Virtual Machine made in VirtualBox and reintialising the Docker Quickstart (that installs the VMin VirtualBox).

Comment: I had a similar problem installing docker. After the installation was completed I had this error message as well. But in my case I had a Windows 8.1 addon called Hyper-V which makes impossible to use VT-x so docker wasn't able to run. To deactivate Hyper-V here it is a link to the post which helped me out: http://superuser.com/questions/869593/intel-virtualization-technology-and-vt-x-wont-work-in-windows-8-1