# Docker for window7 is not working

Tags: docker, boot2docker, docker-machine, docker-toolbox

I have installed Docker toolbox in windows7. When i am running

```
$docker run hello-world
```

i am getting error like-

```
docker: An error occurred trying to connect: Post http://127.0.0.1:2375/v1.22/containers/create: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:2375: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it..
```

Comment: Which version of docker-machine are you using?

Comment: Have you read the requirements for docker for windows beta? It only works on Windows 10 with the newest inside build update!

Comment: @Vonc docker-machine version 0.6.0, build e27fb87

Comment: Try directly (without toobox) `docker-machine ls`, and `docker-machine ssh`

Comment: Through window command prompt when i ran "docker run hello-world". I got that error.when i am typing "docker-machine ls" on window command prompt i am getting like C:\Users\rahul.kumar>docker-machine ls
NAME   ACTIVE   DRIVER   STATE   URL   SWARM   DOCKER   ERRORS

Comment: @ReneM. Just wondering, why are you refering to "Docker for Windows beta"? From my understanding, he is using the regular Toolbox approach, not beta.docker.com, which should work on Windows 7 according to https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/windows/#requirements

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32047660/docker-for-windows-not-working, http://superuser.com/questions/996785/docker-toolbox-error-creating-machine-error-in-driver-during-machine-creation, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32597597/troubleshoot-docker-on-windows-attempt-to-run-hello-world

Comment: Related / maybe helpful: https://github.com/docker/toolbox/issues/162, https://github.com/docker/machine/issues/1094, https://getcarina.com/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-windows-docker-vm-startup/