# Not able to run the default hello-world program in docker on Windows 7

Tags: windows, docker, docker-compose

I just finished installing Docker on my Windows 7 machine using the instructions provided here https://docs.docker.com/windows/step_one/.

During the installation I did not install `Git` and `Virtual Box` as I already had them installed on my machine. After installation I fixed the missing `bash.exe` script issue and got docker working to some extent. But I am not able to run the default `hello-world` docker command. I am getting following error.

I already looked into similar issue mentioned on SO [Troubleshoot Docker-On-Windows attempt to run hello-world](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32597597/troubleshoot-docker-on-windows-attempt-to-run-hello-world) but the error that I am getting here is different. So please do not mark this as duplicate.

```
$ docker run hello-world
docker: An error occurred trying to connect: Post http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.23/containers/create: open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified..
See 'docker run --help'.

$ docker version
Client:
 Version:      1.11.2
 API version:  1.23
 Go version:   go1.5.4
 Git commit:   b9f10c9
 Built:        Wed Jun  1 21:20:08 2016
 OS/Arch:      windows/amd64
An error occurred trying to connect: Get http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.23/version: open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified.


$ docker-machine start default
Starting "default"...
Machine "default" is already running.

$ docker-machine env default
SET DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1
SET DOCKER_HOST=tcp://192.168.99.100:2376
SET DOCKER_CERT_PATH=C:\Users\chandeln\.docker\machine\machines\default
SET DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME=default
REM Run this command to configure your shell:
REM     @FOR /f "tokens=*" %i IN ('docker-machine env default') DO @%i

$ git --version
git version 2.7.4.windows.1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Never mind. I was making a mistake as I was running the commands from Windows terminal instead of Docker quick start terminal. Some of the commands worked initially which made me think of using Windows terminal.

```
$ docker run hello-world

Hello from Docker.
This message shows that your installation appears to be working correctly.
```

Comment: From your output: `REM Run this command to configure your shell:
REM     @FOR /f "tokens=*" %i IN ('docker-machine env default') DO @%i`

Comment: Could you please elaborate the step to resolve this issue

Comment: [ERROR] docker daemon is not running [/bin/lib/functions.plugin.sh:93]